# Using an MS Access Lookup field in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am building an extension to an existing Access database and an accompanying front end programmed in C#.  The original Access database was not designed very well and certainly not designed with future expansion in mind.  For simplicity's sake, lets say the legacy DB has 2 tables: tblEmployee `[empId(AutoNumber), empName(Text)]`  and tblProjects `[prjId(AutoNumber), prjName(Text), prjEmps(Number/Lookup)]`.  Both tables have an AutoNumber primary key.  The Projects table has a multi-value lookup field that allows users to assign multiple employees to a project.  When I query the tblProjects table in Access `SELECT prjId, prjName, prjEmps FROM tblProject;`, the `prjEmps` field lists all the employees' names separated by commas.  However, the problem is when I use the same query in C#, the `prjEmps` returns a string version of a number that is not the `empId` of the employee(s).  I am not sure if it makes a difference, but I am using the `System.Data.OleDb` and `System.Data` namespaces in C#.  Here is the gist my C# code:

```
    string connStr = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
        @"Data Source=" + dbFilePath;
    string query = "SELECT prjId, prjName, prjEmps FROM tblProject;";
    OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, dbConn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    dbConn.Close();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        int prjId = row.Field<int>("prjId");
        string prjName = row.Field<string>("prjName");
        string prjEmps = row.Field<string>("prjEmps");
            MessageBox.Show("Project ID: " + prjId.ToString() + "\n" +
                            "Project Name: " + prjName + "\n" +
                            "Employees: " + prjEmps);
    }
```

I would be happy if I could just get the concatenated list of names, but I would prefer an array of integer keys or the like.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You could try using `System.Data.Odbc` instead of `System.Data.OleDb` and see if that makes any difference. The Access ODBC driver sometimes behaves a bit differently than the OleDB provider.

Answer (score 2):

Use ODBC provider, OLEDB does not supports multi-value lookup field and you get garbage values if you use it to read multi-value lookup field , using ODBC you will get ";" separated values which can then be split into individual values or replace with ",".